# Is it possible to diff a range of changesets in TortoiseHg 2.0?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, tortoisehg-2.0

I'd like to do something like `hg diff -rX::Y` in TortoiseHg and see the result in the TortoiseHg's graphical diff.  Is this possible?  It [seems to have been possible in 1.0](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/1.0/changelog.html#revision-context-menus), but I can't find that context menu item in 2.0.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In TortoiseHg Workbench:

1. Select revision `X`.
2. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and select revision `Y`.
3. Right-click on revision `Y`. In the context menu, click **Visual Diff**.

If you have kdiff3 configured as the diff viewer in TortoiseHg, you'll see the directory diff for `X:Y`.